# Google Map Places Autocomplete result list with only post-code

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete, google-places

I would like to get the only postal codes in result list from autocomplete. here is code

```
     var options  = {types: ['(regions)']};
     var input    = document.getElementById('search_field');
     autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

if i use the "types: ['(postal_code)']" it does not work. any suggestion ?

Comment: Build your own autocomplete with just the postcodes you want?

Comment: but is it not possible through this api, by using kind of event, callback to auto-complete ? this is the last option to create my own list of postcodes and then use jQuery autocomplete